# iOS webview app crash when accessing iPhone photo library

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

iOS webview app crash when accessing iPhone photo library

I was trying to upload photos using wordpress media library,
after i click upload button, 
two options pop up from iphone: photo from iPhone photo library or from cloud.
After clicking iphone photo library option, the app quits.

Any idea is Appreciated

Comment: Please share the error which is shown.

Comment: Do you have permissions of camera and photo library for your app?

Comment: The script was bought from developer. I am not sure. can you please tell me how to check or add permission?

Comment: @DheerajD i have a permission on the app to access photolibrary but on webview. the case was Webview are viewing a page. and the page have Upload image features. when you try to show this on your apps using webview it would crashed your apps because the webview does not have any permission to access it

Comment: Is there any special code to do this? because i have done upload image from photolibrary and camera and does not have any issue. because i already got the permission. but the webview would keep crashing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add Photo library permission in your app

open your `info.plist` file add bellow `xml` code

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow to access photo library.</string>
```

if your app use camera then also add this code in `info.plist` file

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow to access camera.</string>
```

if you don't know to how to open `info.plist` in `xml` code then check this image
[image]

Comment: i already have a permission to access photolibrary. and i have already done this. but when a webview contain access photolibrary somehow that webview is not getting a permission and crashed the apps